# RDS - Change single click option is item via GPO or Registry

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-registry, rds

I have a problem on my servers RDS, my users can not change their themes windows, folder options and many more due to some GPO.

However, in recent days there is a problem concerning the opening of files with a single click. I would like to re-assign the double click to open the files. After several attempts via the registry or GPO I still can not find a solution.

I already tried to diable the ClassicShell with some regestry entry and through GPO but nothing changes. I tried to change the MouseHoverHeigh/Width values and no results.

Do you have an idea to solve this problem?

I also had the problem on some session where the windows theme was set to high contrast. A GPO was created in order to force use the aero.msstyles.

Thank you very much,
Thomas

EDIT 1 : I removed the restriction for user to modify the folder options and I saw that the double-click option was checked but not effective. I unchecked the box and checked it again and now it is working. Is there a way to refresh this option ?

Comment: To to clarify for the single click part. Did you enforce the gpo? Enforcing is like saying "don't over wite these settings" and is diffrent then linking.

Comment: I tried with the simple way "Link" and also with the "Apply" checked

Comment: Whats Resultant Set of Polices say about it? [RSOP.msc](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758010(v=ws.10).aspx) lets you see what options are applied by what policy on your systems (Ran from the users account on the machine). You can also use the [Group Policy management tool](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753298.aspx) to look at Group policy Results section or the group Policy modeling section.